# Safari not registering </br> tags

Tags: html, safari

http://www.xsracing.org/test2/

I am working on that site, and for some reason in the version of safari my boss has, the 
 tags that I use to put space between the images on the sponsors bar do not work. It works fine in every other browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define a css rule to add a space below all the images :

```
img{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Or just for some images :

```
.myImage{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

<img src="myimg.png" class="myImage"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `</br>` tag. It's `<br>`

Comment: or its XHTML counterpart <br />

Answer (score 1):

Use `<br />`, being sure to close it *at the end*.